# PHP: Use external class in a namespace

Tags: php

There is a class which handles the internationalization.

```
<?php

class Language{
    // ...
}
```

Now I created a `renderer.php` file which should handle all injections for HTML.

```
<?php
namespace Renderer;

include_once '../language.php';

function drawUserList(){
    // ...
    $group = Language::translate($groupName);
   // ...
}
```

In this file I need my `Language` class. But my compiler throws the following error message:

`Undefined type 'Renderer\Language'.`

The `Language` class is not part of a namespace. Why adds PHP a namespace to it? And why I am not able to use the class in my namespace function?

PHP Version 7.4.26

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the keywork `use`:

```php
namespace Renderer;
use Language; // indicate to use \Language

include_once '../language.php';

function drawUserList(){
    // ...
    $group = Language::translate($groupName);
   // ...
}
```

or use `$group = \Language::translate()`.